# Get only response headers

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HttpWebResponse: closing the stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536873/httpwebresponse-closing-the-stream)

Using ASP.NET is it possible to make a request and get only response headers? I have to do a request to a big file, but I only need the response headers, i dont care about the content of the file.

I would like to know if there is something similar to get_headers from php (http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php).

Comment: Yes, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536873/httpwebresponse-closing-the-stream

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure how to do this natively, but at a minimum, you could use a custom HTTP handler ([ASHX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228090.aspx)) file to create the headers you need, and return nothing else in the response.

**Update:**

If you set `WebRequest.Method = "HEAD"` then the server should automatically only return the Headers.  This is according to [W3](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html).

Comment: The file is hosted in another server that i dont have control

Comment: very good. i've made a test using what you suggest and that worked like a charm.