# C#: HTTPWebResponse not closing in DLL

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dll

I have a C# DLL written to connect a VB6 (yes, I know - legacy code) industrial application to a third-party web service. My code works the way I want it to now, but I had hit a bit of a snag the other day.

The application works the way I want on the first usage, but hangs on subsequent iterations leading up to an application time-out. After some debugging I found that my method I've used to check for a connection to the web service does not release its objects automatically.

```
    private bool connected()
    {
        string url = "http://location-Im-connecting-to";
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        try
        {
            //  String element to capture response from service
            whatHappened = response.StatusCode.ToString();

            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                //  it's at least in some way responsive
                isConnected = true;
            }
            else
            {
                //  well, at least it returned...
                isConnected = false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //  not available at all, for some reason
            isConnected = false;
            whatHappened = response.StatusCode.ToString();
        }

        //  My solution to closing out the hanging method
        response.Close();
        response.Dispose();
        request.Abort();

        return isConnected;
    }
```

Implementing the three lines to close out the method's objects now allows my DLL to work the way I want for every iteration. So my question is this: even though my brute-force approach has worked for releasing the method's objects it does not have a finessed way of automatically shutting down the method's objects. Does our SO community have any suggestions for cleaning up my solution, or is the above the best I can hope for? Is there a way to wrap up the `HTTPWebResponse` in a `using()` statement as was suggested in the comments for [HttpWebResponse: closing the stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536873/httpwebresponse-closing-the-stream)?

Note: I am aware that the `response.Dispose()` may be redundant, but I am asking for advice on the format for improving the flow of the code.

Comment: What happened when you tried wrapping it in a using statement? Additionally, have a look at a `finally` block for your `try/catch`.

Comment: try using `using` blocks to retrieve the objects, then they will get disposed after use.

Comment: Just use a `using` block around `response`. It *is* an IDisposable object which is a strong hint that it contains expensive resources. In this case, a stream that retrieves results from the web server. The object doesn't know that you *don't* want to read the data, so it keeps the stream open for you to read

Comment: Thanks for the insights. I opted for the solution posted in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968522/c-using-statements-with-httpwebrequests-httpwebresponses). Ironically, I did not see that result come up in my search when I was searching SO for insight into cleaning up my code call the first time. Odd. Regardless, thank you for the feedback.